# Will the baby be a boy or girl?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

In past Harvest Moon games I've played, your baby has always been a boy; in Harvest Moon: A New Beginning, is this still true, or is the gender randomized/fixed to your partner/can be chosen.